# Disable scrolling on a tumblr page

Tags: html, css, tumblr

On my tumblr pages you can start scrolling down which will result in a post AND the sidebar going up and dissapear. The post on the page is small and takes only a third of it, and there shouldn't even be a reason for scrolling to be available. Infinite scroll is disabled. How can i fix it? Link: http://maelacri.tumblr.com/edits

Comment: Scrolling isnt working me. Are you sure its not related to your browser/extensions? Tried a different browser?

Comment: Just checked on another browser - scrolling is working there, too. Plus, it didn't use to be the case when i was using another theme

Comment: Not sure then. As I said, scrolling doesnt work for me (currently on Chrome 67.0, Win10), but you can allways try to disable scrolling by `body { overflow: hidden;}` and maybe even add an `!important`.

Comment: This seems to disable scrolling on the index page, too

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to had to body this:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Adding this makes it impossible to scroll on index page, too

Comment: Then add a div only for that page and put the same css as above.